# How to access nested data in json / php

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am trying to access JSON data. The data structure is as follows:

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gid] => 9d8c-45a1-87cd
            [eig] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [par] => information about field1
                    [desc] => desc of field1
                )

            [datafields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [desc] => field1
                            [type] => string
                        )

                )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gid] => 52bb-435b-a2f0
            [eig] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [par] => information about field2
                    [desc] => desc of field2
                )

            [datafields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            desc => field2
                            [type] => int
                        )

                )
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gid] => 1a93-478d-b33a
            [eig] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [par] => information about field3
                    [desc] => desc of field3
                )

            [datafields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [desc] => field3
                            [type] => float
                        )

                )
        )

)
```

Here is how I proceed. I can access the `gid` parameter.

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach($obj as $row) 
{
    echo $row->gid; // This works
    // echo $row->eig->par; // Does not work
    // echo $row['eig']->par; // Does not work
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to access the `par` and `desc` parameters of each row. I have tried several combinations, but it does not work. Could someone please support me with this?

Comment: Can you show the original JSON, it may help.

Comment: Given what you have shown `echo $row->eig->par;` should work.  Do you get an error?

Comment: Please paste the actual json, I think there could be a confusion between an array and an object.

Comment: Life is easier and FASTER, when you use arrays over objects. Arrays in php are actually hash maps programmed in C. Memory and runtime aside consider using `$obj = json_decode($json, true);`. This will allow you to access your full json as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attention to my question. This works: `echo $row->eig->par;`

Comment: Didn't you say *echo $row->eig->par; // Does not work*

Comment: Yes, I did. But there was a bug in my code.